# Printing with the system dialog when using PMPrintSession

Tags: objective-c, macos, printing

Below is the code I we are using to print on mac. Is there an easy way to allow printing using the system dialog? It looks like at one time [PMSessionBeginDocument](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CarbonPrintingManager_Ref/cpmref_reference/function_group_8.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/PMSessionBeginDocument) & [PMSessionBeginPage](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CarbonPrintingManager_Ref/cpmref_reference/function_group_8.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/PMSessionBeginPage) were a thing, but now all I can find is the NoDialog options.

Are these calls still usable with the latest frameworks? Or is there another way to print using the system dialog?

```
PMPrintSession lPrintSession;
PMCreateSession(&lPrintSession);

PMPrintSettings lPrintSettings;
PMCreatePrintSettings(&lPrintSettings);


PMSessionDefaultPrintSettings(lPrintSession, lPrintSettings);

...    

PMSessionSetCurrentPMPrinter(lPrintSession, lPrinter);

...

PMSetPageRange(lPrintSettings, 1, 1);
PMSetCopies(lPrintSettings, inCopies, false);

if (!inUseSystemDialog) {

    PMSessionBeginCGDocumentNoDialog(lPrintSession, lPrintSettings, lPageFormat);
    PMSessionBeginPageNoDialog(lPrintSession, lPageFormat, NULL);

} else {

    // TODO: What do we do here? Are these calls usable?
    // PMSessionBeginDocument(lPrintSession, lPrintSettings, lPageFormat);
    // PMSessionBeginPage(lPrintSession, lPageFormat, NULL);

}

CGContextRef lGraphics;
PMSessionGetCGGraphicsContext(lPrintSession, &lGraphics);

...

PMSessionEndPageNoDialog(lPrintSession);
PMSessionEndDocumentNoDialog(lPrintSession);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run an `NSPrintPanel` to show the system print dialog. For that, you also need to set up an `NSPrintInfo` object:

```
NSPrintInfo* printInfo = [NSPrintInfo new];
// set printInfo.printer if you want to override the default

PMPrintSettings printSettings = printInfo.PMPrintSettings;
// configure printSettings
[printInfo updateFromPMPrintSettings];

PMPageFormat pageFormat = printInfo.PMPageFormat;
// configure pageFormat
[printInfo updateFromPMPageFormat];
```

Create the panel and run it with that info object:

```
NSPrintPanel* panel = [NSPrintPanel printPanel];
// configure panel; for example, set its options property
NSInteger result = [panel runModalWithPrintInfo:printInfo];
```

Use the info as the basis of your print session:

```
if (result == NSOKButton)
{
    PMPrintSession session = printInfo.PMPrintSession;
    printSettings = printInfo.PMPrintSettings;
    pageFormat = printInfo.PMPageFormat;
    PMSessionBeginCGDocumentNoDialog(session, printSettings, pageFormat);
    PMSessionBeginPageNoDialog(session, pageFormat, NULL);
    CGContextRef lGraphics;
    PMSessionGetCGGraphicsContext(session, &lGraphics);

    ...

    PMSessionEndPageNoDialog(session);
    PMSessionEndDocumentNoDialog(session);
}
```